# pointer declaration in file I/O code

Tags: c, pointers

I am unable to understand this code that how pointers are declared.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void openfile(char *, FILE **);
int main()
{
     FILE *fp;
     openfile("Myfile.txt",fp);

     if (fp == NULL)
        printf("Unable to open file..\n");

     fclose(fp);
     return 0;

}

void openfile(char *fn, FILE **f)
{
    *f = fopen(fn,"r");
}
```

when I run above program, I get 2 warnings...

```
file.c:9:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘openfile’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     openfile("Myfile.txt",fp);
                           ^
file.c:3:6: note: expected ‘struct FILE **’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’
void openfile(char *, FILE **);    
                   ^
```

What does mean by these warnings? Please can you explain, how pointers are used in above code?

Comment: `openfile` wants a pointer to a pointer to a file. Why are you giving it a pointer to a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fp` is `FILE*` as it is declared, not `FILE**`.

`FILE*` is "pointer to `FILE`".

`FILE**` is 'pointer to "pointer to `FILE`"'.

In `openfile()`, it wants to update `FILE*` data, so pointer to `FILE*` is requested.

In conclusion, you should use `openfile("Myfile.txt",&fp);` to use `openfile()`.

It means that you should use `&` operator to obtain the address of `fp` for updating `fp` in `openfile()`.